# Cell border in table

Tags: c#, printing, tabular, flowdocument

I have a table which I am printing. I have added borders to all the cells but I have a problem when the table enters/exits a new page. Then the border is moved/stays at the page depending on the available space each cell is consuming. Is it possible to make this row dependent in sted?

### Here is a picture of the problem

[image]

*The gray line is the page shift.*

### Here is how I have done

```
foreach (Task task in TasksToShow)
        {
            myTable.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            currentRow = myTable.RowGroups[0].Rows[rowCount++];

            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.TaskID.ToString()))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.TaskName))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.TaskResponsible))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.TaskResponsibleDepartment))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.Category))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.Status))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.Priority.ToString()))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.ActualHours.TotalHours.ToString() + "h"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.EstimatedHours.TotalHours.ToString() + "h"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.EstimatedDeploymentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.DesiredImplementationDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.APP.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.APP.EstimatedHours.TotalHours.ToString() + "h"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.APP.ActualHours.TotalHours.ToString() + "h"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.IN.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.IN.EstimatedHours.TotalHours.ToString() + "h"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.IN.ActualHours.TotalHours.ToString() + "h"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.SIS.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.SIS.EstimatedHours.TotalHours.ToString() + "h"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.SIS.ActualHours.TotalHours.ToString() + "h"))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(task.Tags))));

            currentRow.FontSize = 10;
            currentRow.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;

            for (int n = 0; n < currentRow.Cells.Count; n++ )
            {
                currentRow.Cells[n].BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
                currentRow.Cells[n].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
            }
        }
```

Also is there a way to make the cells width dependent on the largest cell and not just making all cells the same width?

Hope you can help.

Comment: Holy moly. 1 word, refactoring!

Comment: What do you mean? I am just adding data here. I can't see how to make this better!?

Comment: How about: `void AddRow(data) { currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(data)))); }`

Comment: Yeah you are right that would make the maintain easier... but that still don't anser my question. I will make some refactoring now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figure out a solution which at least make it looks the same all the way through but I am not fully satisfied with it yet. I have just changed the thikness in the last for loop into this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < currentRow.Cells.Count; n++ ) 
{ 
    currentRow.Cells[n].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 2, 1, 0); 
    currentRow.Cells[n].BorderBrush = Brushes.Black; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to add a border to all cells **and** the table. If the table has no border, the borders of the cells at the border of the table have only half the grid line width.

The grid line width between 2 cells on the same row consists of the cell border width of the left cell plus the cell border width of the right cell. If the cell has no neighbour, the grid width there is only half of the other grid lines. Adding a border for the table adds the border of the none existent neighbour.

```
table.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
table.BorderThickness = new Thickness(.5)

cell.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
cell.BorderThickness = new Thickness(.5)
```

I know, this doesn't solve your problem, but at least the grid lines look nicer.